# suds - type string is 7 bits or 8 bits?

Tags: python, python-2.7, webservice-client, suds

I am using `suds` to call an ASMX web service written in .NET.

An argument in a web method is of type `string`. The WSDL says:

```
  <article>string</article>
```

Can such a parameter contain 8-bit values?

I get an error:

```
   result = super(Text, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2979: ordin
   al not in range(128)
```

But I couldn't find any character in my text string that is being passed though.  What does the error message mean exactly?

--
Edits: Yes, I have found a character \0xe2 in the string that is passed.  It is part of an UTF-8 encoded character sequence `\xe2\x80\x9c` which is the open-inverted commas.  The string is read from a text file encoded in UTF-8.  So I will have to change my question to: how to save a Python string in UTF-8?

I would like to close this question.

Comment: I think your suds client is receiving a non ascii string and is not being able to parse it correctly. Is not about bits in the string, is about encodings. Ascii is only 7bit. Can you place a stack trace or something that give us further hints?

Comment: 0xe2 is â in extended ascii, any chance this is the problem?

Comment: Does the error message mean that it has detected a character 0xe2, and it is an error because it is not within 128?  Doesn't a restriction of 128 mean it's allowing only 7-bit bytes in the variable?